# How to find JSON path if the JSON tree has unique Key in the path of Key whose value is to be extracted?

Tags: java, json, selenium, automation, web-api-testing

I wanted extract value of first "jobId"  but "76ff0515-a200-444a-b5b3-e81e81360b75":" this value is updated every other day.

Can somebody help me in writing JSON path for extracting value of jobId which can be used in Rest Assured testing using selenium?

`{ "76ff0515-a200-444a-b5b3-e81e81360b75": { "state": "COMPLETED", "jobId": "76ff0515-a200-444a-b5b3-e81e81360b75", "jobType": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS", "message": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS- Operation performed on: 3 users", "duration": "00H:00M:03S" }, "c13cc2c0-5ac7-4939-ad2d-901e233f3651": { "state": "COMPLETED", "jobId": "c13cc2c0-5ac7-4939-ad2d-901e233f3651", "jobType": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS", "message": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS- Operation performed on: 0 users", "duration": "00H:00M:01S" }, "00a286e0-00e4-4373-9a31-a236d5145b3b": { "state": "COMPLETED", "jobId": "00a286e0-00e4-4373-9a31-a236d5145b3b", "jobType": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS", "message": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS- Operation performed on: 3 users", "duration": "00H:00M:02S" }, "b4ceb8ee-c56d-4a8e-8327-e5cfde452c23": { "state": "ERROR", "jobId": "b4ceb8ee-c56d-4a8e-8327-e5cfde452c23", "jobType": "ADD_BIZ_UUID", "duration": "00H:00M:02S" }, "b0e86631-e921-4606-81df-80f372993f64": { "state": "COMPLETED", "jobId": "b0e86631-e921-4606-81df-80f372993f64", "jobType": "ADD_BIZ_UUID_FOR_ALL", "message": "OK", "duration": "00H:01M:55S" } }`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: {
    "76ff0515-a200-444a-b5b3-e81e81360b75": {
        "state": "COMPLETED",
        "jobId": "76ff0515-a200-444a-b5b3-e81e81360b75",
        "jobType": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS",
        "message": "UNMIGRATE_BUSINESS- Operation performed on: 3 users",
        "duration": "00H:00M:03S"
    } 
}


I want to fetch value of "jobId" but problem which I am facing is, in the JSON tree "76ff0515-a200-444a-b5b3-e81e81360b75" this value is always unique. How do I write JSON path for fetching a value for which I have to transverse through a value which is always unique

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/java-jsonnode-get-keys